# getting error MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 when deploying firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, mongoose, google-cloud-functions, robo3t

I am trying to run my application on firebase function and even though the deployment has been successfully completed,On running the app I am getting the error **not found**.
Additionally when running on localhost there is no problem.

On further investigation I am getting the below logs which I think points to mongodb connection issue.
Hence if someone can please help me resolve this problem.

let me know if you require any further information from my end.

(using robo3T)

mongoose.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/user', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
})

mongoose.connection.on("error", err => {
     console.log("err", err)
    })
    
    mongoose.connection.on("connected", (err, res) => {
      console.log("mongoose is connected")
    })
```

firebase function:log

```
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461675Z ? app: err MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461717Z ? app:     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:824:32)
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461730Z ? app:     at /workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:380:10
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461739Z ? app:     at /workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461747Z ? app:     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461757Z ? app:     at promiseOrCallback (/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461766Z ? app:     at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1233:10)
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461775Z ? app:     at Mongoose.connect (/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:379:20)
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461783Z ? app:     at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/db/mongoose.js:4:10)
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461792Z ? app:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461801Z ? app:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10) {
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461809Z ? app:   reason: TopologyDescription {
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461817Z ? app:     type: 'Unknown',
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461825Z ? app:     servers: Map(1) { '127.0.0.1:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
2022-09-30T14:11:28.461832Z ? app:     stale: false,
```

Comment: Check locally whether your MongoDB service is running or not. Test your connection with the URL you are using.

Comment: hi I checked locally and its running fine when I am using localhost as url but not working when I am using firebase function url to connect

Comment: You can try and use your mongoDB service name instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1 and see if you are able to connect.Also check if any firewalls are blocking this connection and your mongoDB service is up and running.